# Flutter/Dart: get_cli add more controller to a page

Tags: flutter, dart, get-cli

Is it possible to create multiple controllers using get_cli?
currently, I am doing this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this in terminal:

```
get create controller:"ControllerName" on home
```